# Application restarted unexpectedly on Server 2012 and IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis, iis-8

After user login and doing some concurrency `$.ajax` session get expired unexpectedly or application get restarted...

I have checked every tools to know the main cause such as Win Event log, IIS Log and my custom logging info but there is no proper info ....

but after some googling I crossed to [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TroubleshootingExpiredASPNETSessionStateAndYourOptions.aspx) which said `Inproc` mode is not reliable and unexpected Process Recycling

or the answer of question [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1210757.aspx) which said if you are using `InProc` session state and the `AppPool` spins down, that will automatically reset all of the sessions of logged in users. So make sure you are either using some other method for session state or that the idle timeout of the `AppPool` is longer than the `.NET` session timeout.

can someone tell me what is my wrong ?

or can `$.ajax` limitation posted data or limitation of returned string len from `webmethod` cause this problem  ?

My `web.config` and IIS:

```
<sessionState timeout="120" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

From what I have tested I can see Application get restarted not `AppPool` or `w3wp`.

I have get exception in `Application_Error` but still there is no clue to know

```
   void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _logging = new Logging(Global.LogPath);
        Exception exp = Server.GetLastError();
        _logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "An error accured through the application, EX{0}", exp.ToString());
    }
```

I also follow [this link](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194) and did what that said but nothing different.

**UPDATE:**

in the other side I have a generic handler to process some `$.ajax` request (concurrency requests)

```
  public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        base.ProcessRequest(context);

        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string action = request["Action"];
        switch (action)
        {
            case "LoadThumbnails":
                response.Write(LoadThumbnails(request.GetStudyUid()));
                break;
            case "LoadDetails":
                string detailsSeriesUid = request["seriesUID"];
                string detailsStartPoint = request["strStartPoint"];
                string detailsLengthPoint = request["strLenghtPoint"];
                response.Write(LoadDetails(request.GetStudyUid(), detailsSeriesUid, detailsStartPoint, detailsLengthPoint));
                break;
.
.
.
```

sometime application  get restarted in `LoadThumbnails()` and sometime in `LoadDetails()`.

they may returns large JSON string so is there limitation for `response.Write()` that reset application ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: check log files maybe the application ended unexpectedly because of error in your website code not iis error

Comment: Thanks for your comment , yes I checked that but I can find the cause...

Comment: Do you added Elmah in project?

Comment: No I didn't, I have custom logging system but I have to use `try-catch` everywhere I want to log.

Comment: active elmah and add log here

Answer (score 0):

Aha, After many headache I have resolved the problem properly....

As Microsoft mentioned this problem occurred because of high disk I/O and I have a concurrence `$.ajax` requests to get stream from Service and Write it down to wbserver H.D.D so I am going to post the solution here may will help someone.

**Step 1 :** So I improved my `Application_End` logging as:

```
 void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Logging == null)
            Logging = new Logging(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"]);
        int logLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogLevel"].ToString());
        Logging.Mode = (LoggingMode)logLevel;
        Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Application_End is running...");
        HttpRuntime runtime = (HttpRuntime)typeof(HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null);
        if (runtime == null)
        {
            Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Runtime is null...");
            return;
        }
        string shutDownMessage = (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null);
        string shutDownStack = (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null);
        Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Application restarted because of , Message:{0} , Stack:{1}", shutDownMessage, shutDownStack);
    }
```

**Step 2:** And my log after unexpectedly restarting was:

> > 2016-12-28 13:33:41.4791 [Error]  [myApp.dll] Application_End is running...
> >        2016-12-28 13:33:41.4822 [Error] [myApp.dll] Application restarted because of     Message:IIS configuration change
> >         HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
> >         HostingEnvironment caused shutdown , Stack:   at     System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
> >            at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
> >            at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
> >            at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
> >            at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.StopProcessing()
> >            at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
> >        at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
> >        at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

**Step 3:** Googling about **IIS configuration change** at last found
proper [Microsoft KB about unexpected ASP.Net application shutdown](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480)

**Step 4:** Download `All supported x64-based versions of Windows Server 2012 R2` package and installed it on mentioned server.

**Step 5:** Calm down and be happy because the problem has been resolved by 4 mentioned steps!!!!

I hope it be useful for you.